# Is it public knowledge that the Avengers went back in time?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

After the events of *Avengers: Infinity War* (and then once more after *Avengers: Endgame*), a lot of people became very interested in Thanos, and very quickly. Even as far back as *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, there were references to those battles in airplane movie catalogs or books.

However, these glimpses at what the general public of the MCU knows are vague and fleeting. **Is it public knowledge within the MCU that the Avengers went back in time?** Or do only the parties involved know exactly what happened?

Answer (score 22):

### Unknown but probably not

The only real indication of what the public knows is from *Spider-Man: Far from Home* from the school video

> Over five years ago, half of all life in the universe, including our own
> Midtown High...was wiped from existence.
>
> Then eight months ago, a band of brave heroes brought us back.

So clearly the Avengers seem to have revealed *some* of what happened, and people seem to know the name Thanos, and it's extremely unlikely that time travelling would not have been mentioned in this video if this were also public knowledge.

Also, given the history of the Avengers taking unilateral action (Sokovia Accords remember), such a drastic act as time travelling is probably not something they would wish to advertise.

Comment: You have an odd double negative - "it's extremely unlikely that time traveling would not have been mentioned". This suggests that it *was* mentioned, but the rest of this answer indicates otherwise.

Comment: They hunted down and defeated Thanos, took the infinity stones, and snapped everyone back.  Don't need to mention those things were not related.

Comment: Nope, its just the same is "its likely that time travelling *would* have been mentioned" but in a way that implies a negative.

Comment: Since the end of Hawkeye makes it know that there are secrets around black widows death, I would say the other details are not know to the public.

Comment: I think it’s the passive voice that is making that “would not have been mentioned” clause be misunderstood—on first read I assumed that the would-be mentioner was the Avengers, in terms of what they shared with the public, which makes the sentence contradict everything else. On reread, after having finished the sentence, it became clear that you meant that _the video_ would have mentioned it. I think changing it to include the video as the subject in active voice prevents that confusion: “it’s extremely unlikely that the video would not mention time traveling if this was public knowledge”

Comment: Of course, at that point, the double negative phrasing feels more awkward (it was better in the passive voice, it seems to me? but then we had confusion on who would be doing the mentioning), so “it’s extremely likely that the video would mention time traveling if this was public knowledge” would be clearer still. If the negative is desired, “fail to mention” feels better than “not mention” to me, there. (Anyway, in case it was unclear, +1 either way, I just initially shared Nuclear Hoagie’s confusion and was thinking about how it could be avoided.)

Comment: If everyone died, and you went back in time and prevented them all from dying, how would they know they died?  Not saying your answer is wrong, but the narrative of the school video you quoted defies logic.  In their timeline, they never died.

Comment: @Styxsksu It's also apparently common knowledge that Cap liked to say "I could do this all day" (It's the title of a big show-stopping Broadway musical number), even though he only ever said that while fighting somebody (e.g. Ironman, Thanos, himself, etc.), not in front of a big crowd of witnesses.  It's common knowledge to *us*, the movie watchers, but doesn't seem like it should be well known *in-universe*...

Comment: In their timeline they were dead for 5 years and the Avengers brought them back. They just didn't age in the interim. They were never prevented from being snapped, that's the whole point of Endgame.

Comment: I don't think that "dead" is quite the right term. For five years, they simply *didn't exist*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Or that it didn't happen in that order.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: +1. That was the original plan before Thanos destroyed the Stones. Time travel was plan B. The public does not need to know the details.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

The public was not aware of the Avengers’ time travel until Scott Lang revealed it in his book, *[Look Out For The Little Guy!](https://books.google.com/books/about/Look_Out_for_the_Little_Guy.html?id=tIarEAAAQBAJ)* where he recounts his experience of being part of the [time heist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#2020s) and fighting Thanos and his army in *Endgame*.

He mentions in the book's introduction that Bruce Banner (the Hulk) and Clint Barton (Hawkeye) encouraged him to share his story with the world because they felt that people deserved to know the full story behind Thanos and the Blip. In the book, Scott says:

> One day, Bruce “the Hulk” Banner and Clint “Hawkeye” Barton took me out for lunch. They said they were concerned that the world didn’t really *know* what had happened with Thanos and the Blip and our long struggle to finally put things right again.
>
> At first, as I usually do when confronted with heavy topics, I made a joke: “I’m pretty sure at least half the world knows what happened.”
>
> Bruce responded that yes, of course, billions had *experienced* these jarring and mind-bending events, but they didn’t know the full story behind them. And ultimately, that’s what people need the most to get through and get past traumatic events: a narrative that helps it all make sense.
>
> “Okay,” I agreed. “Solid plan. So who are you going to get to tell that story?”
>
> Clint answered, “You, Scott. You’re the guy who got scooped up in all this pretty recently. You’ve still got one foot in their world. And you’re a guy everyone likes…and trusts.”
>
> And Bruce sealed the deal: “It’s tough stuff, and no one knows how to keep it light like you.”

> They’d supply me all the archival footage and documentation, take me anywhere I needed to go, and let me ask as many questions as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the close friends/family of the Avengers are familiar with what actually took place however, the public only knows that some blip occurred which restored 5 years.

Having said that - I would imagine they'd think that the Avengers went back in time because how else from a regular standpoint would you reason a 'blip' bringing people back who were gone. Its either through some crazy spell-casting or time-travel.

Most of the movies mention casual references of the blip along with the latest Spiderman setting the precedent for time-travel.

So I am leaning towards a yes.

Comment: Remember that the time-travelling was to obtain the Infinity Gems, not to 'bring people back' (at least not directly). Once the Gems were collected, it was the use of the glove (effectively 'crazy spell casting') that 'undid' the 'snap' and ended the 'blip'.